# How can i include the list of tables and figures with small caps in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, small-caps

I want to have all section titles and "list of figures" and "list of tables" in small caps in the TOC and in the main text. 
I managed to create them in small caps in the main text and the section titles for the TOC also, but "list of figures" and "list of tables" do not appear in small caps in the TOC.
How can I achieve that "list of figures" and "list of tables" appear in small caps in the TOC?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  while it's nice to know that you've been successful in making the section titles appear in small caps, it's not possible to know how to tackle the other requests without knowing what document class you're using.  (different document classes handle these things differently.)  so please provide a small compilable file beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem for us to experiment with.  (this is known as an "mwe" or "minimum (non)working example".)

Comment: Easy solution, add the [short caption] using \MakeUppercase{...}

Comment: From GOM (Grumpy Old Man) You could do it with the `memoir` class but as you haven't given an MWE showing what you have done I'm not going to show you how to do it with `memoir`.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, the `listformat` option from the caption package only affects the label before the caption text.

This solution allows you to continue using `\caption`.  Short captions (if added) will also be converted to small caps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\normalcaption=\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[2][\empty]% #1=short caption (optional), #2 = caption
 {\ifx\empty#1\relax \normalcaption[\MakeUppercase{\small#2}]{#2}
  \else \normalcaption[\MakeUppercase{\small#1}]{#2}
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption[short caption]{normal caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```